# Bad communication between Gazebo Harmonic and ROS 2

Tags: gazebo, ros2, simulation

I have a robot system defined in an SDF with the following:

```
<sdf version='1.9'>
    <model name='simple_ddr' canonical_link='base_link'>

        <plugin filename="gz-sim-diff-drive-system" name="gz::sim::systems::DiffDrive">
            <left_joint>joint_wheelL</left_joint>
            <right_joint>joint_wheelR</right_joint>
            <wheel_separation>0.4</wheel_separation>
            <wheel_radius>0.1</wheel_radius>
            <odom_publish_frequency>0.1</odom_publish_frequency>
        </plugin>

        <plugin
            filename="gz-sim-sensors-system"
            name="gz::sim::systems::Sensors">
            <render_engine>ogre2</render_engine>
        </plugin>

        
        <link name='base_link'>
          <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>

            <inertial>
                <mass>1.0</mass>
                <inertia>
                    <ixx>0.011041666666666665</ixx>
                    <ixy>0.0</ixy>
                    <ixz>0.0</ixz>
                    <iyy>0.02604166666666667</iyy>
                    <iyz>0.0</iyz>
                    <izz>0.03541666666666667</izz>
                </inertia>
            </inertial>

            <collision name='base_link'>
              <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
              <geometry>
                <box>
                  <size>0.55 0.35 0.1</size>
                </box>
              </geometry>
            </collision>

            <visual name='base_link'>
              <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
              <geometry>
                <box>
                  <size>0.55 0.35 0.1</size>
                </box>
              </geometry>

              <material>
                  <ambient>0.0 0.6 0.6 1</ambient>
                  <diffuse>0.0 0.6 0.6 1</diffuse>
                  <specular>0.0 0.6 0.6 1</specular>
              </material>
            </visual>

            <sensor name="imu_sensor" type="imu">
                <always_on>1</always_on>
                <update_rate>1</update_rate>
                <visualize>true</visualize>
                <topic>imu</topic>
            </sensor>

            <sensor name='gpu_lidar' type='gpu_lidar'>"
                <pose relative_to='lidar_frame'>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
                <topic>lidar</topic>
                <update_rate>10</update_rate>
                <ray>
                    <scan>
                        <horizontal>
                            <samples>640</samples>
                            <resolution>0.01</resolution>
                            <min_angle>-1.396263</min_angle>
                            <max_angle>1.396263</max_angle>
                        </horizontal>
                        <vertical>
                            <samples>1</samples>
                            <resolution>0.01</resolution>
                            <min_angle>0</min_angle>
                            <max_angle>0</max_angle>
                        </vertical>
                    </scan>
                    <range>
                        <min>0.08</min>
                        <max>10.0</max>
                        <resolution>0.01</resolution>
                    </range>
                </ray>
                <always_on>1</always_on>
                <visualize>1</visualize>
            </sensor>
        </link>
      
        <joint name='joint_wheelL' type='revolute'>
            <pose relative_to='base_link'>-0.2 -0.2 0.0 0 0 0</pose>
            <parent>base_link</parent>
            <child>wheelL</child>
            <axis>
            <xyz>0 1 0</xyz>
            <limit>
                <lower>-inf</lower>
                <upper>inf</upper>
            </limit>
            <dynamics>
                <damping>10</damping>
                <friction>1</friction>
                <spring_reference>0</spring_reference>
                <spring_stiffness>0</spring_stiffness>
            </dynamics>
            </axis>
        </joint>
        
        <link name='wheelL'>
            <pose relative_to='joint_wheelL'>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
            <inertial>
            <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
            <mass>0.050000000000000003</mass>
            <inertia>
                <ixx>0.001625000000000001</ixx>
                <ixy>0</ixy>
                <ixz>0</ixz>
                <iyy>0.00025000000000000011</iyy>
                <iyz>0</iyz>
                <izz>0.001625000000000001</izz>
            </inertia>
            </inertial>
            <collision name='wheelL_collision'>
            <pose>0 0 0 -1.5707963300000001 0 0</pose>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder>
                <length>0.050000000000000003</length>
                <radius>0.10000000000000001</radius>
                </cylinder>
            </geometry>
            </collision>
            <visual name='wheelL_visual'>
            <pose>0 0 0 -1.5707963300000001 0 0</pose>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder>
                <length>0.050000000000000003</length>
                <radius>0.10000000000000001</radius>
                </cylinder>
            </geometry>

                <material>
                    <ambient>1.0 0.0 0.0 1</ambient>
                    <diffuse>1.0 0.0 0.0 1</diffuse>
                    <specular>1.0 0.0 0.0 1</specular>
                </material>
            </visual>
        </link>

        <joint name='joint_wheelR' type='revolute'>
            <pose relative_to='base_link'>-0.2 0.2 0.0 0 0 0</pose>
            <parent>base_link</parent>
            <child>wheelR</child>
            <axis>
            <xyz>0 1 0</xyz>
            <limit>
                <lower>-inf</lower>
                <upper>inf</upper>
            </limit>
            <dynamics>
                <damping>10</damping>
                <friction>1</friction>
                <spring_reference>0</spring_reference>
                <spring_stiffness>0</spring_stiffness>
            </dynamics>
            </axis>
        </joint>

        <link name='wheelR'>
            <pose relative_to='joint_wheelR'>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
            <inertial>
            <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
            <mass>0.050000000000000003</mass>
            <inertia>
                <ixx>0.001625000000000001</ixx>
                <ixy>0</ixy>
                <ixz>0</ixz>
                <iyy>0.00025000000000000011</iyy>
                <iyz>0</iyz>
                <izz>0.001625000000000001</izz>
            </inertia>
            </inertial>
            <collision name='wheelR_collision'>
            <pose>0 0 0 -1.5707963300000001 0 0</pose>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder>
                <length>0.050000000000000003</length>
                <radius>0.10000000000000001</radius>
                </cylinder>
            </geometry>
            </collision>
            <visual name='wheelR_visual'>
            <pose>0 0 0 -1.5707963300000001 0 0</pose>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder>
                <length>0.050000000000000003</length>
                <radius>0.10000000000000001</radius>
                </cylinder>
            </geometry>
                <material>
                    <ambient>1.0 0.0 0.0 1</ambient>
                    <diffuse>1.0 0.0 0.0 1</diffuse>
                    <specular>1.0 0.0 0.0 1</specular>
                </material>
            </visual>
        </link>

        <link name='caster'>
            <pose relative_to='joint_caster'>0 0 0.0 0 0 0</pose>
            <inertial>
                <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
                <mass>0.005</mass>
                <inertia>
                    <ixx>0.001625000000000001</ixx>
                    <ixy>0</ixy>
                    <ixz>0</ixz>
                    <iyy>0.00025000000000000011</iyy>
                    <iyz>0</iyz>
                    <izz>0.001625000000000001</izz>
                </inertia>
            </inertial>
            <collision name='caster_collision'>
                <geometry>
                    <sphere>
                        <radius>0.025</radius>
                    </sphere>
                </geometry>
                <surface>
                    <friction>
                        <ode>
                            <mu> 0.0 </mu>
                            <mu2> 0.0 </mu2>
                        </ode>
                    </friction>
                </surface>
            </collision>
            <visual name='caster_visual'>
                <geometry>
                    <sphere>
                        <radius>0.025</radius>
                    </sphere>
                </geometry>
            </visual>
        </link>

        <joint name='joint_caster' type='fixed'>
            <pose relative_to='base_link'>0.2 0 -0.075 0 0 0</pose>
            <parent>base_link</parent>
            <child>caster</child>
        </joint>
      
        <frame name='joint_body' attached_to='base_link'>
            <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
        </frame>


        <frame name="lidar_frame" attached_to='base_link'>
            <pose>0.8 0 0.5 0 0 0</pose>
        </frame>

    </model>
</sdf>
```

I put everything into 2 launch files, a start_gazebo launch file and a spawn_robot launch file:

```
def generate_launch_description():

    pkg_robot_models = get_package_share_directory('robot_models')
    #######################################################################################################################################
    # Start gazebo

    world_file = os.path.join(pkg_robot_models, 'worlds', 'test_world.sdf')

    world_launch = IncludeLaunchDescription(
            PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([
                PathJoinSubstitution([
                    FindPackageShare('ros_gz_sim'),
                    'launch',
                    'gz_sim.launch.py'
                ])
            ]),
            launch_arguments={
                'gz_args': world_file + ' -r -v 4'
            }.items()
        )

    #######################################################################################################################################
    # Run the node
    return LaunchDescription([
        world_launch
    ])
```

```
def generate_launch_description():

    pkg_robot_models = get_package_share_directory('robot_models')
    #######################################################################################################################################
    # Spawn robot system

    robot_filepath = os.path.join(pkg_robot_models, 'models', 'simple_DDR', 'model.sdf')

    ROBOT_MODEL = 'simple_DDR'

    start_gazebo_ros_spawner_cmd = Node(
        package='ros_gz_sim',
        executable='create',
        arguments=[
            '-name', ROBOT_MODEL ,
            '-file', robot_filepath,
            '-x', '0.0',
            '-y', '0.0',
            '-z', '0.3'
        ],
        output='screen',
    )

    #######################################################################################################################################
    # Specify the name of the package and path to xacro file within the package
    os.environ["GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH"] = os.path.join(pkg_robot_models, "models", 'simple_DDR', 'model.sdf')
    os.environ["LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE"] = "1"

    bridge_laser = Node(
            package='ros_gz_bridge',
            namespace='',
            executable='parameter_bridge',
            name='lidar',
            arguments=["/lidar/points@sensor_msgs/msg/LaserScan[gz.msgs.LaserScan", "--ros-args", "-r", "/lidar/points:=/laser_scan_cloud"]
        )
    
    bridge_clock = Node(
            package='ros_gz_bridge',
            namespace='',
            executable='parameter_bridge',
            name='lidar',
            arguments=["/clock@rosgraph_msgs/msg/Clock[gz.msgs.Clock"]
        )


    bridge_tf = Node(
            package='ros_gz_bridge',
            namespace='',
            executable='parameter_bridge',
            name='lidar',
            arguments=["/model/simple_DDR/tf@tf2_msgs/msg/TFMessage[gz.msgs.Pose_V"]
        )
    
    bridge_odom = Node(
            package='ros_gz_bridge',
            namespace='',
            executable='parameter_bridge',
            name='lidar',
            arguments=["/model/simple_DDR/odometry@nav_msgs/msg/Odometry[gz.msgs.Odometry"]
        )

    #######################################################################################################################################
    # Run the node
    return LaunchDescription([
        start_gazebo_ros_spawner_cmd,
        bridge_laser,
        bridge_clock,
        bridge_odom,
        bridge_tf
    ])
```

Result: communication does not work. Point cloud in RVIZ says Showing [0] messages of [0] received, no transform data or frame are sent, ...

Edit: Some additional information. ROS 2 Iron, Gazebo Harmonic, build of ros_gz was done with GZ_VERSION=harmonic

Comment: Are you getting data from the LiDAR at all? Echo it and verify.

Comment: @Nikolai when I do gz topic -e -t /lidar and  gz topic -e -t /lidar/points I get messages

Comment: OK, but what about the ROS topic? Are you receiving anything there? RVIZ listens to ros topics not gazebo topics

Comment: @Nikolai ROS topic receives nothing, that is the issue. I do ros2 topic echo /laser_scan_cloud

Comment: Is there a reason why you built ros_gz from source instead of using the official binary (with apt)? also, you don't need to have many ros_gz_bridge, one is enough, and you can pass a yaml file containing all the bridge config. Finally, I see that the three bridge nodes have the same name, this might cause conflicts.
Another thing you can check, is make sure that your ros_gz bridge executable links with the correct gz-harmonic libs (use `ldd`)

Comment: @ejalaa12 also noticed the naming issue and corrected, error persisted. I built from source because the default version of gazebo for ros iron is fortress, not harmonic, and since there is some command changes from one version to the other I wanted to use the ones of harmonic since it is the latest version

Comment: True, but that is if you install gazebo using `sudo apt install ros-iron-ros-gz` which would install the default ros-iron, which is fortress. So I'm guessing you also compiled gazebo from source for harmonic ? You can use those instructions https://gazebosim.org/docs/harmonic/install_ubuntu to install gazebo harmonic without compiling it manually.

Comment: And then you can install ros-gz for harmonic using: `sudo apt install ros-iron-ros-gzharmonic` see [here](https://gazebosim.org/docs/harmonic/ros_installation#-gazebo-harmonic-with-ros-2-humble-iron-or-rolling-use-with-caution-)

Comment: The point I'm getting at, is if gz-bridge was compiled with a different gazebo version than the simulation is running with, the bridge won't work.

Comment: @ejalaa12 gazebo was installed through apt install following the guide in the gazebosim webpage, and gz-bridge was built from source predefining the environment variable GZ_VERSION to harmonic

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151725/discussion-between-ejalaa12-and-pdaranda661).

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [this](https://github.com/gazebosim/ros_gz/blob/ros2/ros_gz_sim_demos/launch/gpu_lidar_bridge.launch.py) launch file? Might be something with how you run the bridge.

Comment: I run it and works properly. I will take a look at the launch file and the sdf files associated and update in a comment to this answer with problem source.